# Extract first and last transaction date in R

Tags: r

I have a transaction data set as follows.

```
   id   purchase_date
    A   6/1/18
    A   6/2/18
    A   6/10/18
    A   6/15/18
    B   6/4/18
    B   6/5/18
    C   6/3/18
    C   6/7/18
    C   6/8/18
    C   6/9/18
    C   6/12/18
    D   6/21/18
    D   6/30/18
    D   7/1/18
    E   3/23/18
```

I want to take only first and last transaction for each id. My output should be as follows.

```
ID  FIRST_PURCHASE_DATE LAST_PURCHASE_DATE
A   6/1/18              6/15/18
B   6/4/18              6/5/18
C   6/3/18              6/12/18
D   6/21/18             7/1/18
E   3/23/18             3/23/18
```

My actual data has 200k unique ids. Any advice will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `first` and `last` from `dplyr` after grouping by 'ID'

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  summarise(FIRST_PURCHASE_DATE = first(purchase_date),
            LAST_PURCHASE_DATE  = last(purchase_date))
```

---

The above assumes that 'purchase_date' is ordered by 'ID'.  If it is not, `arrange` after converting to `Date` class and then take the `first` and `last`

```
library(lubridate)
df1 %>%
  arrange(ID, mdy(purchase_date)) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  summarise(FIRST_PURCHASE_DATE = first(purchase_date),
            LAST_PURCHASE_DATE  = last(purchase_date))
```

Comment: Or if the question is asking about the earliest and latest date, then I think you could do
 `df1 %>%
  rename(ID=id) %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  summarise(FIRST_PURCHASE_DATE = min(as.Date(purchase_date, format = "%m/%d/%y")),
            LAST_PURCHASE_DATE  = max(as.Date(purchase_date, format = "%m/%d/%y")))`